# Omitting acute accent on a display with limited character set

Tags: acentuación

I have to display Spanish on a display with fixed/limited character set. The display is used to control devices like showers, door access etc. So it displays messages like "Remaining credits/time", "Access granted", "Press button to start/stop" and things like that. It is missing the capital letters with acute accent:

Á Í Ó Ú

I have zero Spanish knowledge so the question is:

Do the acute accents only indicate pronunciation or or also semantics? Would it be fine to just substitute those chars with `A I O U` or do I need to take special considerations?

Comment: I'm guessing that you will also run into an issue with "Ñ". And if you ever have to drop the tilde from "AÑO" then there will be a lot of hilarity!

Comment: @PeterM The letter Ñ is available. Only capital with acute accent are missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Electronic displays with a fixed height tend to omit the accents altogether (e.g. older displays in trains, the metro, buses, bus stops):

[image: PRÓXIMO TREN LLEGARÁ EN: → PROXIMO TREN LLEGARA EN:]

For short messages where the context is obvious it is usually unambiguous what is meant, so in practice there are rarely issues omitting these accents.

---

Note that you do occasionally see accented [small caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) used instead as a workaround in such displays:

[image] [image]

<sup>(note, the above signs are Catalan, not Spanish)</sup>

Similar to what is done for the enye "Ñ" character:

[image]

Comment: Good point about the "small caps". I could potentially substitute Ó with ó and it would probably look OK on the display. I will test it with the available font, Á and Í however, definitely look lowercase.

Comment: Although I made a joke comment above on the OPs question about Ñ, what do electronic signs do for that letter? Because it is a distinct letter and not an accented one.

Comment: +1. To make it explicit: the accents *can* affect semantics -- there are words that differ only in the presence or absence of an accent, e.g. *tomo* "I take" vs. *tomó* "(s)he took" -- but as you say, most of the time it's not hard to figure out what was meant.

Comment: @ruakh You don’t even need to go that far, in the very first photo given, the display reads LLEGARA, which is a subjuntivo imperfecto form that does not mean the same as the intended future form LLEGARÁ—not that the former conjugation is at all likely to be seen on a display like this.

Comment: @RomanOdaisky: Indeed!

Comment: @PeterM The character set from my display also uses "small caps" to make the top diacritics fit into the area. See https://i.paste.pics/a487b7e41405fad0ff5d9493f6b8c10d.png.